# what is the name of this scrollable android widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

What is the name of this [widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXqt.png)??

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXqt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Number Picker** in XML and customize as per your need.

Comment: Are you have any example on github or other repo?